# CloudKit "Deploy to Production" doesn't show record changes, "Deploy" greyed out

Tags: icloud, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

When I click "Deploy to Production" in CloudKit, it looks like this: [image: icloud deploy to production screen]

As you can see, there's two updates to indexes. But the problem is, that's not the only change I made to my schema - there's new fields on some record types. They're not showing up at all.

What's more, even if I wanted to deploy just these two index changes, the Deploy button is greyed out! What's going on? How do I convince CloudKit to recognise the changes I've made?

Answer (score 0):

You need Edit and manage permissions for this iCloud Container.

Even if your account is added as an admin in the team you still need to have manage iCloud permission.